# Unable to explain why c++ vector allocation fails

Tags: c++

So I have a basic code that creates a structure of vectors, and I am noticing that it fails beyond a particular threshold, not entirely sure of why this happens. I only tried two scenarios where my struct has a size of

- Case 1: 100000
- Case 2: 200000

I am attaching the code and some basic profiling that I did. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

#### Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct vec
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> A;
    std::vector<double> B;
};

int main()
{
    vec a[100000]; // case 1
    // vec a[200000]; // case 2

    return 0;
}
```

#### Case-1

```
$ valgrind --tool=massif ./test_mat

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:            ./test_mat
Massif arguments:   (none)
ms_print arguments: massif.out.4149
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    KB
71.01^   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::#
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
     |   :                                                                   #
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->Mi
     0                                                                   40.14

Number of snapshots: 4
 Detailed snapshots: [2 (peak)]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0              0                0                0             0            0
  1      2,076,837           72,712           72,704             8            0
  2     42,094,451           72,712           72,704             8            0
99.99% (72,704B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->99.99% (72,704B) 0x4EC4424: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
  ->99.99% (72,704B) 0x40108D1: _dl_init (dl-init.c:72)
    ->99.99% (72,704B) 0x40010C8: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so)
```

#### Case -2

```
$ valgrind --tool=massif ./test_mat
==4225== Massif, a heap profiler
==4225== Copyright (C) 2003-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote
==4225== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4225== Command: ./test_mat
==4225==
==4225==
==4225== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4225==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFE6D8128
==4225==    at 0x10888E: main (in /home/ramsr/osu/vanderpol/src/test/test_mat)
==4225==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4225==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4225==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4225==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4225==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4225==
==4225== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4225==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFE6D8120
==4225==    at 0x4A2C650: _vgnU_freeres (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so)
==4225==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4225==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4225==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4225==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4225==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4225==
Segmentation fault
```

Memory info of the computer I am running this on:

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       13006188     1447828     9700384          40     1857976    11297440
Swap:       4194304         268     4194036
```

Comment: Why are you mixing std::vector and C style arrays?

Comment: `std::vector<vec> a(100000);` (and unrelated, a big-arse vector of struct of vectors, one of which is a vector of vector... sooner or later the madness has to end; just saying).

Comment: Yes, creating a vector of structs fixes the issue, I was just trying to match the numbers, size of the stack, and the array allocation

Comment: @N3UR0515 I get only 4800000 stack used `100,000 * 48` not sure why the reported value is 8,388,608

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind output says exactly what is happening here

```
==4225==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4225==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4225==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4225==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4225==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

You either need to allocate arrays dynamically in this case, or increase the stack size.

Comment: Yes, got that part, I was unable to match the numbers and explain why the array of structs were failing, anyways, thanks!